# Precompiled header error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015, precompiled-headers

I beg your pardon if this question has been already answered, but I have been trying to implement precompiled headers in my game engine with no success so far.

My precompiled header is called `UtilBase.h`:

```
#pragma once

#if !defined(NF3D_UTIL_BASE_H)
#define NF3D_UTIL_BASE_H

// This is a precompiled header.
#pragma message("Compiling precompiled header.")

// Include engine specific files.
#include <Utilities\Platform\Types.h>

// Include external header files (STL, Win32 API, Direct3D 11, etc)

// There are some typedefs here:  
typedef __int32 int32; // And so on.

#endif
```

Although this is against the standards, I included `UtilBase.h` in other headers because I need access to some of its contents. It is also included in all `.cpp` files, first line, from the current project (the solution has two projects).

I need it in some headers because it stores some `typedef`s that are used in function declarations. For example, I have some file called `Window.h`:

```
#pragma once // And include guards that are omitted here
int32 NF3DCreateWindow();
```

The associated source file is called `UtilBase.cpp` and has only one line of code:

```
#include <Utilities\UtilBase.h>
```

The project has been set up correctly in my opinion:

[image]

for all platforms and configurations.

`UtilBase.cpp` has this setting:
[image]

However, when I compile I get this error:

> 1>Source Files\Utilities\UtilBase.cpp(2): error C2857: '#include' statement specified with the /YcD:\New Frontiers\NewFrontiers3D\Header Files\Utilities\UtilBase.h command-line option was not found in the source file

which points to the only line in `UtilBase.cpp` (`#include <Utilities\UtilBase.h>`).

Why does this happen and what can I do to make it work? I will gladly send any further information about this scenario. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You are doing it wrong.  The #include for the precompiled header must always be the first #include in the .cpp file.  It is therefore quite unnecessary and wrong to include it in a .h file.  Since that would mean that you include that .h file first.

Comment: @HansPassant Please check the edit and tell me if I'm still wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally made it! For anybody in my situation here is what I did: in project settings, `Precompiled Header File` tag, I added `$(ProjDir)\Header Files\Utilities\UtilBase.h` and it was evaluated to the full path of the file. The correct way is to simply add the file: `Utilities\UtilBase.h` and that's it.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score -2):

try #ifndef instead of #if !defined